# UIImageView shrinks on iPhone 4

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview

I use UIImageView in my project, and when I test it on iPhone 4 simulator the image shrinks:
[image]

However, on iPhone 5 the image is OK:
[image]

I use `Scale to Fit mode` (I tried different modes), `Autoresize Subview` and `Autolayout` are unchecked. Why this happening?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please try with scaletofitmode?

Comment: whats your nib view's height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your AutoSizing:

[image]

You should remove the inner arrows if you don't want to see any change when moving between iPhone 4 and 5

Comment: Thank you, it worked for me. I ll accept your anwser in 5 minutes.